# Difference between tendency of benzene and thiophene to undergo sulfonation

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, organosulfur-compounds

Why does thiophene possess a greater tendency to undergo sulphonation than benzene? I came across this reaction which employs the use of sulphuric acid to separate thiophene from commercially prepared benzene.

Comment: The activation energy is less for the the thiophene reaction because thiophene is less aromatic than benzene.

Comment: Not because aromatic conjugation in thiophene imparts negative charge to the carbon?  Draw thiponene Kekule type structures and see ... .

Comment: As ron said thiophene is less aromatic than benzene, but perhaps more importantly thiophene is an electron-*rich* ring which leads to greater reactivity with electrophiles (which are electron-*poor*). Pyridine is as aromatic or slightly less aromatic than benzene, but pyridine is *very* unreactive towards electrophiles.

Comment: I came across a Quora answer saying that in thiophene, the 6 electrons are delocalised over 5 atoms but in benzene, the delocalisation is over 6 atoms. Therefore, electron density is higher in the former.

Comment: @Orthocresol as an aside -- pyridine can be made to "wake up" for electrophiles by N-oxidizing it.

Answer (score 4):

In the chapter **Aromatic five-membered ring heterocycles with one heteroatom** in *Organic Chemistry* by  J. William Suggs (2002) the following explanation can be found (pp. 403-404) which summarizes the thoughts already pointed out in the comments:

> The resonance stabilization energy of benzene is greater than that of these heteroaromatic compounds.
>   The order of aromaticity is benzene > thiophene > pyrrole > furan.
>
> […]
>
> All three of these ring systems undergo electrophilic aromatic substitution and are much more reactive than benzene.
>   In part, this reactivity difference arises because the rate-determining step in electrophilic aromatic substitution is the first step, which breaks up the aromatic $\pi$ system.
>   Since thiophene, pyrrole, and furan have less stabilization to lose than benzene, the intermediate is lower in energy and the overall reaction proceeds more rapidly.
>
> […]
>
> All three of these heteroaromatic rings undergo electrophilic aromatic substitution, preferentially at C-2. 
>   The reactivity order is pyrrole > furan > thiophene because of several factors, including the electronegativity of the heteroatom and the resonance stabilization of the aromatic ring.